How do you prove $g([[X,Y],Z],T) = g([X,Y],[Z,T])$ in the last step of proving the Riemannian curvature identity $R(X,Y,Z,T) = 1/4g([X,Y],[Z,T])$
I am puzzled by the last step in the proof that $R(X,Y,Z,T) = \frac{1}{4}g([X,Y],[Z,T])$, which is Proposition 3.17 in Gallot et alia's Riemannian Geometry Third Edition.  Gallot et alia use brackets a lot, which is very interesting but different for me.
Here is a fleshed out version of Gallot's proof.
The manifold is a Lie group. The metric g is bi-invariant. X,Y,Z, and T are left-invariant vector fields on the Lie group.
Start with the definition of the (0,4) curvature tensor in terms of the (1,3) curvature tensor: $R(X,Y,Z,T) = g(R(X,Y)Z,T)$.
The (1,3) curvature tensor is defined as $R(X,Y)Z$ = $D_Y(D_XZ)- D_X(D_YZ) + D_{[X,Y]}Z)$.
It is easy to show that $D_XY = 1/2[X,Y]$ (etc.) so that:
$R(X,Y)Z = 1/4[Y,[X,Z]] - 1/4[X,[Y,Z]] + 1/2[[X,Y],Z]$.
Using the Jacobi identity for brackets (which is $[X,[Y,Z]] + [Y,[Z,X]] + [Z,[X,Y]] = 0$), we have
$R(X,Y)Z$  = $1/4[[X,Y],Z]$.
Substituting this into the definition for the (0,4) curvature tensor gives: $R(X,Y,Z,T) = 1/4g([[X,Y],Z],T)$.
The final step in the proof is that $1/4g([[X,Y],Z],T)$ = $1/4g([X,Y],[Z,T])$.  Can someone explain this step?

You should say what the assumptions are for the manifold and Riemannian metric.

Thanks for the comment.  The manifold is a Lie group.  The metric g is bi-invariant.  X,Y,Z, and T are left invariant vector fields on the Lie group.

You should edit your question and provide those details.

Thank you.  I have now done this.

Using the metric property of the connection, $$g([W, Z], T) = -2g(D_ZW, T) = -2D_Z(g(W,T)) + 2g(W, D_ZT) = -2D_Z(g(W,T)) + g(W, [Z, T]),$$ so it suffices to show that the first term vanishes (I don't know why, but it probably has to do with invariance).

Thank you!  I can't find a reference to "metric properties of the connection" that gives the first equality (I have Lee and Gallot).  Can you provide such a reference to explain this to me?

Sure. Perhaps that was not the right name, but it's the condition that $\nabla$ preserves the metric as can be seen in the proof here.

And the first equality I got from "it is easy to see that $D_X Y = (1/2)[X,Y]$" applied to left-invariant fields $Z, W.$ Similarly for the last equality. I do not guarantee that this is the right approach, so tell me if you see any mistake.
